# Liferay IDE - cannot install to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, liferay, liferay-ide

I'm trying to install liferay IDE (from tutorial: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/installation) 
The problem appears after I checked the Liferay IDE checkbox and press Next. Error popup appears telling me this: "org/sat4j/minisat/core/AssertingClauseGenerator java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError".
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class is used by the Eclipse p2 framework which has to do with installing new plugins.  It appears something is malformed in your eclipse installation for the Update manager to not be able to find that sat4j class.  The requirements for Liferay IDE are to use the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, which can be found on this page: [Eclipse Downloads](http://eclipse.org/downloads/)  Its the top link.

If you are using that package and still see the error try restarting eclipse and give it the `-clean` commandline flag in eclipse.ini which might clear the NoClassDefFoundError.

A final option would be to down an eclipse that has Liferay IDE pre-installed, which you can find at this page: [Liferay IDE Downloads Page](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide)

Comment: Hi, I already using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, so that is not the case. I've put "-clean" command in eclipse.ini file, restarted IDE, the same problem.

Comment: Do you have the sat4j bundles in your plugins folder? org.sat4j.core_2.3.0.v20110329.jar, org.sat4j.pb_2.3.0.v20110329.jar, org.slf4j.api_1.6.1.v20100831-0715.jar

Comment: It sounds like something is corrupt with your installation.  You could try one of the pre-packaged bundles on the liferay-ide downloads page (use the combobox dropdown) and give that a try as a fall-back.

Comment: Yes I have sat4j in plugins folder. Okei, I will download eclipse pre-packaged bundle. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can install Liferay IDE via eclipse marketplace. (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried installing from marketplace, still the same popup apears.

Comment: Could be your Eclipse install is somehow weird .. Maybe you get a fresh copy of Helios and try it again ...

Answer (score 1):

Download Eclipse from [HERE](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide) its already including Liferay SDK. Just chose what eclipse to use (I am using Juno)

This will solve your problems :)